# Как "достучаться" до атрибута экземпляра класса через @classmethod?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

По условию задачи, требуется написать класс, конструктор которого бы принимал дату строкой в формате 'день-месяц-год', а затем именно через `@classmethod` метод требуется извлечь дату и преобразовать в число.
Я столкнулся с проблемой, на мой взгляд, очевидной, что через `@classmethod` я не могу "достучаться" напрямик до атрибута экземпляра класса. Через геттер тоже не получилось. Получилось только через `@property`, но меня постигла неудача, т.к. мне необходимо делать определённые преобразования с тем, что возвращает данный метод, а Python ругается на то, что у объекта класса property нет возможности сделать эти преобразования.

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, data: str):
        self._data = data

    @classmethod
    def data_to_int(cls):
        return cls.data.split('-')

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data


data = Data('18-10-2004')
print(Data.data_to_int())   #AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'split'
print(data.data_to_int())
```

Comment: 1 - Класс сам по себе не имеет доступа к полям существующих объектов этого класса. 2 - Если у вас будет несколько объектов класса, значение из какого из объектов должно получиться?

Comment: @insolor т.е. это технически невозможно?  Может быть я как-то неправильно понял условие задачи... Не хотел её просто выкладывать полностью, хотел решить сам, но вот конкретно выдержка про `@classmethod ` : 
** Реализовать класс «Дата», функция-конструктор которого должна принимать дату в виде строки формата «день-месяц-год».
В рамках класса реализовать два метода. Первый, с декоратором @classmethod.
Он должен извлекать число, месяц, год и преобразовывать их тип к типу «Число»**

Comment: А второй метод?

Comment: @insolor Второй я ещё даже не смотрел) Застрял на первом, но вот:

Второй, с декоратором `@staticmethod`, должен проводить валидацию числа, месяца и года (например, месяц — от 1 до 12).
Проверить работу полученной структуры на реальных данных.

Comment: Технически это возможно, но при создании объектов нужно например добавлять каждый новый объект в список объектов внутри класса. Но опять же остается вопрос - из какого именно из созданных объектов должен извлекать значения метод класса? Можно конечно нужный объект передавать как параметр в метод класса, технически это будет соответствовать заданию, но проще было бы сделать обычный метод.

Comment: @insolor Большое Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
class MyDate:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.date = string
    
    @classmethod
    def date_to_int(cls, obj):
        return obj.date.split('-')

a = MyDate('12-21-2001')
print(MyDate.date_to_int(a))
```